# How to add custom Authorization Header for tile requests in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, basic-authentication, vector-tiles

I am using the [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) plugin to load pbf vector tiles on a leaflet map. The API that I retrieve the vector tiles requires an authorization header to be passed. In Mapbox GL js this can be resolved by using the [transformRequest](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map) option. Example:

```
var baseLayer = L.mapboxGL({
    accessToken: token,
    style: 'myStyle',
    transformRequest: (url, resourceType)=> {
        if(resourceType == 'Tile' && url.startsWith(TILE_SERVER_HOST)) {
            return {
                url: url,
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + key }
            };
        }
    }
}).addTo(leafletMap);
```

How can I do something similar in Leaflet to bypass the 401 authorized message that I am getting?

For reference vector layer constructor from the plugin:

```
var vectorTileOptions = {
    rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile
};

var pbfLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(vectorTileUrl, VectorTileOptions).addTo(leafletMap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Github issue https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/89 describes a `fetchOptions` attribute you can pass when instantiating your layer that will be used as [`fetch` options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options) to [retrieve the tiles](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/master/src/Leaflet.VectorGrid.Protobuf.js#L127).

You should be able to do

```
var vectorTileOptions = {
    rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
    fetchOptions: {
        headers: { 
            Authorization: 'Basic ' + key
        }
    }
};

var pbfLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(vectorTileUrl, VectorTileOptions).addTo(leafletMap);
```